# Command prompt print dialog command

Tags: c++, command-line, command-prompt

Is there any way a C++ commandline program on Windows can produce a graphical GUI print dialog for printing to a printer, just like usual GUI programs? I've combed through [this webpage](http://www.xoc.net/works/tips/xp-command-line-tools.asp) and it seems there are only commands that print files in the background to a pre-determined printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command-line applications in Windows still have full access to everything that GUI-mode applications do (the only difference is they start out with a console, whereas GUI-mode applications do not).

So you can still call all of the regular [printing functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686799%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from GDI.

Comment: hmm... I was thinking of specifically system() calls... are there any that might serve the same purpose?

Comment: That's not the normal way of printing from an application.